# How do I get access permissions right for my backup?

Tags: permissions, backup

I have a backup server in my LAN which mounts the home dir of user@laptop and creates a backup each hour using a python script.

The problem that I'm having is that I get some hundred "permission denied" errors from rsync. Some files won't copy if I start the backup as root, others won't copy if I start it as user.

The first thought that came to my mind was to set group ownership of home from `user` to `root` recursively. But I'm not sure if I should really do that..

Does anyone know how to proceed with this?

**Some info about the setup:**

`uid` and `gid` numbers are identical for user and root on both computers.

This is how I import/export home:

Export with: `/etc/exports`

```
192.168.178.10(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,root_squash)
```

Mount with: `/etc/auto.user`

```
-fstype=nfs4,ro,tcp 192.168.178.20:/home/username
```

Comment: use no_root_squash option

Comment: the option `ro` means "read-only". I would suggest you change your mount option from `ro` to `rw` (read/write) when you're performing the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `export` line says

```
192.168.178.10(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,root_squash)
```

The `root_squash` entry means "when remote user root tries to access the file, pretend the user is `nobody` instead.  This means the remote root user has no privileged access at all.

Instead change `root_squash` to `no_root_squash`.  ie

```
192.168.178.10(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Now the remote root user will have root level read access to the files.

Comment: It works perfectly with this fix. Thanks! :)